# Selenium - Search for an element within element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I want to hold element references in files somewhere. and then in run time search for elements withing referenced elements in Selenium how to do that.

---

For example- a Frame contains multiple text boxes -and multiple frames of similar properties exist where the textboxes are also duplicate. Something like I wanna reference the text box under a particular frame. But i wanna predefine the frame. and the specify that search under that frame[Something like Aliases in Testcomplete]

---

For Example - similar concept exist in Cheezy's Page-Objects. but not quite.

Comment: A code example is probably better than english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have a structure like this:

```
<div class='some class'>
  <input class='input-button' value='submit'>Submit</input>
</div>
<div class='some class2'>
  <input class='input-button' value='submit'>Submit</input>
</div>
```

and you want to find the first 'Submit' which is within the 'some class' div, you can do this:

```
parent_element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class='some class']")
child_element = parent_element.find_element(:xpath, ".//input")
```

p.s. this is ruby code.